# Single-ended analog signal to differential

Tags: analog, differential, transmission

I need to transmit 2 analog signals over a cable in a noisy environment.

**How to transmit them as differential ?**

Given that :

- Each signal can be used to inject and receive current (< 130 kHz, < 100 uA, bidirectional)
- Each signal can be used to measure potential difference
- My system works at 3 VDC

The main problem being : I need the transmission to be bidirectionnal.

What component or circuitry should I use ? I am a beginner at analog signals transmission...

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the length of the cable, but for a noisy environment you probably need to look at a 4-20mA current loop transmitter. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to explain in detail what your application is and why you're trying to do this. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Are you saying that the two analogue signals are both bidirectional. Are you also saying that they are independent and are unrelated to each other?

Comment: You better stick to reliable methods and use 4 wire shield STP cable grounded